# Counting partial values or conditional values

Tags: mysql, count, subquery, distinct

I hope someone can lend an assist and some advise here. I'm trying to get a fairly complex result and not sure if I can do it as one query with subqueries, a union, or simply separate queries to be merged into excel after the fact.

I'm working with a legacy database from my predecessor with the following tables:
Business (columns working with: id, sector, state)
Forms (columns working with: Submitted (Y/N), id, business_id)
Inventory (Columns working with: In_stock (Y/N), id, form_id)

I'm trying to get a final result that looks like this:

```
| SubmittedForms | Unsubmitted Forms | Sector | State |
|-----------------------------------------------------|
|       10       |         5         |  Agr   |  UT   |
|       0        |         7         |  Chem  |  MT   |
|       2        |         1         |  Bio   |  OK   |
|       13       |         0         |  Chem  |  NM   |
```

The main problem I'm getting is that while submitted forms doesn't need any further arguments and is a simple count, the unsubmitted forms are dependent on the Inventory.in_stock='Y'. Here's my query for the submitted forms:

```
SELECT COUNT(Forms.id) AS Submitted, Business.sector, Business.state
FROM Forms
JOIN Business ON Forms.business_id=Business.id
WHERE Forms.submitted='Y'
GROUP BY Business.state, Business.sector
```

Unfortunately, I can't seem to get the unsubmitted forms number to calculate correctly. It just returns the total count of rows where in_stock is Y for that sector.

If it's easier to run a separate query for Submitted and Unsubmitted that's fine for the end result but I need some help getting the correct count of Unsubmitted forms with the in_stock flagged as Y. Also, I attempted to use a COUNT DISTINCT but takes way too long, was still running after 10 minutes. Another complication I can envision in a single query option is the possibility of 0/null values in either Submitted or Unsubmitted forms

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN Forms.submitted = 'Y' THEN 1 END) SubmittedForms,
       COUNT
        ( CASE WHEN Forms.submitted = 'N'
                AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                               FROM Inventory
                              WHERE form_id = Forms.id
                                AND in_stock = 'Y'
                           )
               THEN 1
           END
        ) UnsubmittedForms,
       Business.sector Sector,
       Business.state State
  FROM Forms
 RIGHT
 OUTER
  JOIN Business 
    ON Forms.business_id = Business.id
 GROUP
    BY Business.sector,
       Business.state
;
```

Another option, which might perform better:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN Forms.submitted = 'Y' THEN 1 END) SubmittedForms,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Forms.submitted = 'N' THEN 1 END) UnsubmittedForms,
       Business.sector Sector,
       Business.state State
  FROM ( SELECT *
           FROM Forms
          WHERE submitted = 'Y'
             OR id IN ( SELECT DISTINCT form_id
                          FROM Inventory
                           AND in_stock = 'Y'
                      )
       ) Forms
 RIGHT
 OUTER
  JOIN Business 
    ON Forms.business_id = Business.id
 GROUP
    BY Business.sector,
       Business.state
;
```

Comment: Thanks, that shows me how to get the submitted/unsubmitted columns in one result, but doesn't factor in the In_stock variable for unsubmitted documents.

Comment: @KevinO.: Ah, sorry. So, I'm confused. You wrote that "the unsubmitted forms are dependent on the Inventory.in_stock='Y'", but you didn't explain what the dependency *was*. It looks like `Inventory` is a child of `Forms`, not the other way around; so are you looking for a count of unsubmitted forms that have *at least one* `Inventory` record with `in_stock = 'Y'`? Or are you looking for a count of `Inventory` records that have `in_stock = 'Y'` and belong to unsubmitted forms? Or . . . ?

Comment: My apologies, in retrospect you're right, was unclear. Yes, my predecessor basically went down in hierarchy: Business, Forms, Inventory, so inventory is a child of Forms. I am looking for a count of unsubmitted forms that have at least one `Inventory` record with `in_stock = 'Y'`

Comment: Thanks for the assist, the first selection worked great and  I have no doubt the second will work as well. I kind of got thrown into SQL work without a lot of background on it so I'm still learning the capabilities for the most part, didn't know about COUNT CASE before, now I do, thank you!

Comment: @KevinO.: You're welcome! To clarify a bit, there's no distinct `COUNT(CASE ...)` feature. The way it works is, `COUNT(...)` counts all the non-null values (so, for example, `COUNT(1)` or `COUNT(0)` is equivalent to `COUNT(*)`, whereas `COUNT(NULL)` always evaluates to zero), and a `CASE` expression evaluates to `NULL` if none of the conditions is satisfied. (This can be made more explicit by using an `ELSE` clause -- `CASE WHEN ... THEN 1 ELSE NULL END` -- but when the `CASE` expression is wrapped in a `COUNT`, I don't generally bother.)